# How to connect a signal from my class to a slot in the MainWindow class?

Tags: qt, serversocket

I am new in Qt.

I want to develop a TCP server program that inform the user whenever a new connection arrives.

I have made a widget project and added a new class for socket programming. In the interface of my class, there is an QTcpserver object called my server (QTcpserver *myServer).

I can connect the newConnection() signal to my class's slots like this:

```
connect(myServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(aConnectionArrived()));
```

But, I want to connect the newConnection() signal to a slot in the MainWindow class.

I would be grateful if you let me know how I can access ui through signal and slots from my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new signal in your widget and connect it to your TCP server (you can connect a signal to another one):

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
private:
    QTcpServer* myServer;
signals:
    void newConnectionAccepted();
}
```

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(): QWidget()
{
     connect(myServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SIGNAL(newConnectionAccepted()));
}
```

So, you can create you connection in your main window:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
connect(myWidget, SIGNAL(newConnectionAccepted()), this, SLOT(processNewConnection()));
}
```

By doing this, you don't break SOLID principles by exposing your TCP server object outside of your widget.

Comment: I did not know that we can connect a signal to another one.